# Prolog: count number of predicates relating to an atom

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog

I have a set of facts in Prolog, such that:

```
likes(alice,   burger).
likes(bob,     burger).
likes(charlie, burger).

likes(bob,     sandwich).
likes(charlie, sandwich).

likes(alice,   muffin).
```

I want to know what's the most popular dish (burgers in the example above). I'm not interested in the 2nd, 3rd, etc most popular for this query as the list of preferences can be really long.

I'm struggling to write this query in SWI-Prolog. Can you help me?

Comment: Fair: basically I got to `findall` and `bagof`, and I also found `aggregate_all(count, PREDICATE, Count)`. but I'm blocked here and I don't know how to piece these together of even if that's the right path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
most_popular(Popular) :-
    findall(X, likes(_, X), Xs),
    sort(0, @=<, Xs, Items),
    clumped(Items, Counts),
    sort(2, @>=, Counts, [Popular|_]).
```

- findall/3 pulls them out of the Prolog database into a list.
- clumped/2 really does run length encoding, but if they are sorted first that is the same as counting them.
- then sort them by the count (`sort/4` first parameter is which part of the term to sort by. `Item-Count` is really the compound `-(Item,Count)` so 0 sorts with normal term sorting, 1 gets the Item name to sort by or 2 gets the Count to sort by) and unify the first element of the resulting list as the answer.

```
?- most_popular(Item-Count).
Count = 3,
Item = burger
```

Comment: Your code finds the first food alphabetically. If you change `burger` to `zurger` it returns `muffin` (the first one alphabetically after the change)

Comment: The corrected last line should be: `sort(2, @>, Counts, [Popular|_]).`. I really appreciate your answer, if you edit it to be correct I'll accept it.

Comment: @gphilip good catch; I've edited and fixed, with explanation

Comment: Almost perfect but note that the comparison operator in the last line also needs to be changed.

Comment: @gphilip @> will remove duplicates, I think @>= might be more appropriate but maybe in this case it doesn't matter